# Scraping a Monospace Website Table into R

Tags: r, web, scrape

I am trying to scrape the following website into R:

https://www.njcaa.org/sports/bsb/2021-22/div1/teams/arizonawesterncollege?sort=ab&pos=h&tmpl=teaminfo-network-monospace-template

And wish for it to end up in a table format...

Can someone point me in the right direction of where to start using this format specifically as the plan is to scrape many of these?

Ideally, each section (of the three) is their own individual df

Answer (score 0):

Here I only display the last one.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

"https://www.njcaa.org/sports/bsb/2021-22/div1/teams/arizonawesterncollege?sort=ab&pos=h&tmpl=teaminfo-network-monospace-template" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  .[[4]] %>% 
  drop_na()

# A tibble: 26 × 14
     No. Player      G    TC    PO     A     E  FPCT DP    SBA   RCS   `RCS%` PB   
   <int> <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
 1    22 Jorge …    14    11     5     6     0     1 -     1     -     -      -    
 2    10 Chris …    12     5     1     4     0     1 -     1     1     .500   -    
 3     7 Wesley…    34     5     3     2     0     1 2     -     -     -      -    
 4    31 Qiang …    15    19    14     5     0     1 2     -     -     -      -    
 5     1 Luis F…     6    34    30     4     0     1 -     1     1     .500   2    
 6    30 Juan G…    17     8     3     5     0     1 2     3     1     .250   -    
 7    29 Roland…    13     4     0     4     0     1 -     -     -     -      -    
 8    19 Eric R…    32     6     6     0     0     1 1     -     -     -      -    
 9    16 Enmanu…     4     1     0     1     0     1 -     -     -     -      -    
10     2 Derek …    21     3     3     0     0     1 -     -     -     -      -    
# … with 16 more rows, and 1 more variable: CI <chr>
```